# Aggregating only specific line items

Tags: sql

I tried aggregating the 'Units' and 'Amount' fields to remove the line item that was reversed (the Apples), but it also grouped the other line items (Pears) which I need to be listed on separate lines.  Is there any way to remove line items that are reversed without using an aggregate function?

```
SELECT Account, Code, Item, SUM(Units) As ‘Total Units’, SUM(Amount) AS ‘TotalAmt’
FROM Fruit
GROUP BY Account, Code, Item
```

TABLE

```
Account    Code      Item   Units   Amount
-------  --------   ------- -----   ------
10325      5972      Apple  1   .50
10325      5972      Apple  -1     -.50
10325      7231      Pear   1   .62
10325      7231      Pear   1   .62
10431      5972      Apple  1   .50
```

RESULT

```
TABLE
Account    Code      Item   Units   Amount
-------  --------   ------- -----   ------
10325      7231      Pear   2   1.24
10431      5972      Apple  1   .50
```

Comment: Is the result the desired result?  If so then you're aggregating the pear and I thought you didn't want that...

Comment: Is there an order number or anything which would make sales/return row unique?  I'm thinking of two subqueires, one for sales, one for returns then a left join where the return is null; but I need some way of ensuring we don't eliminate too much or too little even a ID field which is auto incremented would work. (can you describe the whole table or are the 5 columns it?)

Comment: The result is not what I want to see.  I just want to remove the item that was reversed and it's original entry.  There is a unique sequence number.

Comment: Is there a tie between the sale and reversal other than the units and amount?  Saiy I had 3 additinoal sales to account 10325 for code 5972 as apples each 1 unit at 50.  How would I know which ONE to remove? or it doesn't matter so long as JUST 1 is removed?  if just one then we need to first somehow group /flag the two records and then use that flag to remove the duplicates.

Comment: This is one of the reasons companies have RMA's (returned Merchandise authorizations) so they know what order to tie the return to and apply the credit correctly.  Which RDBMS system is this?  SQL Server? mySQL?  I want to know if window functions are available.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Query (15.0.4721.1000)  There isn't anything that indicates it is a return other than the reversal of the unit and the amount with the corresponding line item data.  It appears that Data-Entry has to manually re-enter it with all of the information to match since occasionally all line item column information isn't the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
SELECT Account, Code, Item, SUM(Units) As ‘Total Units’, SUM(Amount) AS ‘TotalAmt’
FROM Fruit
GROUP BY Account, Code, Item
having sum(Units)>0
```

Comment: This didn't work.  When I ran the query with no aggregate function and compared the sum of the units and amount, it didn't agree.  Because I added the aggregate in the Having statement, it required that I added it as in the Group By.

Comment: in your sample data, you are aggregating then why you dont use aggregate? I dont't get your point..it will make sense if you make it clear with more explanation

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have window functions available, we can create a row number partitioned by account, item unit and amount, join on those fields and then join on the RowNumber so we don't assign a return to multiple sales.

The return could be tied to the wrong sale so I don't really like this response; but if we don't care about that and simply want to eliminate the sale records... this should do it.

Assumption: Only returns would be negative units and negative amounts.

```
SELECT Sales.Account, Sales.Code, Sales.Item, Sales.Units, Sales.Amount 
FROM (SELECT Account, Code, Item, Units , Amount, Row_number() over (partition by Account, Code, Item, Units, Amount order by UniqSeq) RN
      FROM Fruit
      WHERE UNITS >= 0) Sales
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Account, Code, Item, Units , Amount, Row_number() over (partition by Account, Code, Item, Units, Amount order by UniqSeq) RN
           FROM Fruit
           WHERE UNITS < 0
             AND amount < 0) Returns
  on Sales.Account = Returns.Account
 and Sales.Code = Returns.Code
 and Sales.Item = Returns.Item
 and Sales.Units *-1 = Returns.Units
 and Sales.Amount *-1 = Returns.Amount
 and Sales.RN = Returns.RN
WHERE Returns.Account is null
```

and OrderID, or a ID which is auto increment for each row...

If I assume oracle:

```
with  Fruit (uniqSeq, Account,    Code,      Item,   Units,   Amount) as 
(
select 1, 10325,      5972,  'Apple',  1,   .50 from dual union all
select 2, 10325,      5972,  'Apple',  -1,     -.50  from dual union all
select 3, 10325,      7231,  'Pear',   1,   .62  from dual union all
select 4, 10325,      7231,  'Pear',   1,   .62  from dual union all
select 5, 10431,      5972,   'Apple',  1,   .50  from dual )

SELECT Sales.Account, Sales.Code, Sales.Item, Sales.Units, Sales.Amount 
FROM (SELECT Account, Code, Item, Units , Amount, Row_number() over (partition by Account, Code, Item, Units, Amount order by UniqSeq) RN
      FROM Fruit
      WHERE UNITS >= 0) Sales
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Account, Code, Item, Units , Amount, Row_number() over (partition by Account, Code, Item, Units, Amount order by UniqSeq) RN
           FROM Fruit
           WHERE UNITS < 0
             AND amount < 0) Returns
  on Sales.Account = Returns.Account
 and Sales.Code = Returns.Code
 and Sales.Item = Returns.Item
 and Sales.Units *-1 = Returns.Units
 and Sales.Amount *-1 = Returns.Amount
 and Sales.RN = Returns.RN
WHERE Returns.Account is null
```

[image]

and here's the view with the join with the select showing the "returns" derived table eliminating the where clause... so you can see why filtering on returns.account is null works...

[image]

Comment: There could be another apple added.  There is a sequence number column which lists a unique id number for each line item.

Comment: I'm just getting back to this.  Windows function is available, but I keep getting the error msg "Can't add table '(' ".  Any ideas why it isn't working?  I tried to paste in the query, but it said that it was too long.

Comment: Which RDBMS?  i've updated to show how it would work with oracle.  note I'm assuming `uniqseq` exists as you've indicated such a column exists but not defined a name for it.  but even if not oracle, the above shoudl work for SQL server less the "FRUIT" CTE.

Comment: I am using SQL Server.  To make sure we're on the same page, the unique id is assigned to each line item entry.  If an item is reversed, the reversal line item is assigned a new unique id number.

Comment: The above should still work.  you could test it be taking the from dual on each of the lines in the cte.  The only issue as I pointed out earlier is that we can't tie the reversal to the "correct sale" just a sale with the same account, code and item (which could be for a different customer?)

Comment: I got the query to work.  (The actual query was more complicated.)  I limited the columns and it worked.  When I checked the results the total units and amounts were incorrect.  I found that  the Data-Entry staff do not always reverse the line item by the same number of units or amount as the original entry.  Is there any way around this?  I tried just partitioning it by the account, code and items and still didn't return the correct info.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: No.  As we have no way of knowing what account/code the reversal ties to.  The best we could do would be tie it to the account/code item itself  as in the last image above, but we wouldn't know which "one" it really applies to.  Without an RMA tying back to the original order number, or an original order number itself.  I cant see how to do this.  I would take a step back and ask really...what are we trying to achieve and why?  Why is it important to eliminate the sales records just show both!  $500 sales on account ABC with $75 in returns to ABC... total sales less returns for ABC 425.

Comment: I believe that you're correct that there is no way of doing this.  I was trying to keep it simple, but it would be more like boxes of apples and pears with number of items in each box.  I need to see the number of boxes sold and the number of items.  This is for medical billing where it is necessary to see how many individual services/procedures performed and the number of units.  Thanks for trying!

Comment: To me we're missing data.  If it's medical related, i'm sure the data exists systems/billing wouldn't work well without it.  maybe i'm missunderstanding what "account" refers to.. if that uniquely identifies a customer.... then maybe... but we can't eliminate the "returns/refunds/credit/rebills"  but I'd stick with ordering by the account and date for readbility.

Comment: The system has a means of reversing the charge, but it removed it from the users view.  They came up with their own method of doing this and it is very messy data.  "Account" is the customers unique identifier.  It seems like your query should work, but it is also removing items it shouldn't.  I can't figure out why.  I'm going to stop for now.  This has been a known issue, but I was trying to find some way of correctly reporting the information.

Comment: FYI - It was only removing items where the code had been entered and removed back and forth several times.  Too much to figure out!

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't merge the billing data.  I'd show each record on its own merits to avoid confusion if customer calls in.  Now you should only show records "BILLED" If it's not on an invoice I wouldn't show it unless this is a "unbilled" screen...